# Scipy minimize fmin - problems with syntax

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a function which takes several arguments (one array and two floats) and returns a scalar (float).
Now I want to minimize this function by varying two of the arguments: the two floats.
The array is "unpacked" inside the function at its contents (arrays and floats) are then used.

How can this be done using SciPy's fmin function? I am having a very hard time figuring out the right syntax for this..

The function is something like:

```
def func(x, y, data)
    data1=data[0]
    data2=data[...]
    ...
    ...
    result = ...x...y...data1...data2... #result is a scalar (float)
    return result
```

What should `scipy.optimize.fmin` look like in this case?

```
optimize.fmin(func, ???)
```

Many thanks in advance!

All the best,
p.p.

Answer (score 5):

`scipy` assumes that the arguments are in an array. You can define a helper function:

```
def helper(xy):
    return func(xy[0], xy[1], data)
```

and minimize it with `optimize.fmin`:

```
optimize.fmin(helper, np.array([x0, y0]), ...)
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to sort it out and tried to answer my own question, but "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking". I'll post the answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in SciPy's [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin)! I am just not used to the programming "lingo" of the documentation... (although the documentation has been VERY useful for a newbie as myself).

So, the way to do it is the following:

- Instead of defining the function (to be minimized) as in my question, it should be defined as

  > ```
  > def func(x, *args) #it is literally "*args"!
  >     y=x[0]
  >     z=x[1]
  >     data1=data[0]
  >     data2=data[...]
  >     ...
  >     result = ...y...z...data1...data2... #result is a scalar (float)
  >     return result
  > ```
- Now, the `optimize.fmin` function should be

  > ```
  > optimize.fmin(func, x0=[y_estimate, z_estimate], args=(data))
  > ```

Apparently (maybe I'm wrong) when you provide the array `x0` (initial guess) to the `optimize.fmin` function, it then knows that the it will have to optimize an array with the "size" of `x0`. All other data you need in your function has to be given in the tuple `args` (in this example there is only one array in the tuple `args`, but it could be `args=(data1, data2, ...)`, in which case you wouldn't need to unpack it inside the function).

Summary: the initial guess `x0` is just an array; the extra arguments `args` is just a tuple; the function should be (literally!) defined as def `func(x, *args)`; the array `x` and the tuple `args` can then be 'unpacked' inside the function (with `y=x[0]`, `z=x[1]`, ... and `data1=args[0]`, `data2=args[1]`, ...).

Comment: Minor point but I think you mean data1=args[0], data2=args[...] in your definition of func above.